# How to see what user conntect to SQL Server when Integrated Security=True

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, frameworks, entity

I get a message "CREATE TABLE permission denied in database "DB"" when I try to create EF context from my app in intergrated security = true.

How I can see from what user IIS connects to SQL Server and give appropriate permissions?
It may be john\mypc or someone else, but I want to know exact username.

Comment: Generally you will need to give SQL server permissions for your Apppool

Answer (score 0):

If not sure with one account the users connect to your SQL Server instance you can create a [Logon Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/logon-triggers?view=sql-server-ver15).

There are many examples in the internet, one from [here](https://www.netwrix.com/how_to_create_sql_server_logon_trigger.html):

```
CREATE DATABASE LogonAudit /* Creates db for storing audit data */
USE [LogonAudit]
CREATE TABLE LogonAuditing /* Creates table for logons inside db */
(
    SessionId int,
    LogonTime datetime,
    HostName varchar(50),
    ProgramName varchar(500),
    LoginName varchar(50),
    ClientHost varchar(50)
)
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [LogonAuditTrigger] /* Creates trigger for logons */
ON ALL SERVER 
FOR LOGON
AS

BEGIN
DECLARE @LogonTriggerData xml,
@EventTime datetime,
@LoginName varchar(50),
@ClientHost varchar(50),
@LoginType varchar(50),
@HostName varchar(50),
@AppName varchar(500)

SET @LogonTriggerData = eventdata()

SET @EventTime = @LogonTriggerData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/PostTime)[1]', 'datetime')
SET @LoginName = @LogonTriggerData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
SET @ClientHost = @LogonTriggerData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ClientHost)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
SET @HostName = HOST_NAME()
SET @AppName = APP_NAME()

INSERT INTO [LogonAudit].[dbo].[LogonAuditing]
(
SessionId,
LogonTime,
HostName,
ProgramName,
LoginName,
ClientHost
)
SELECT
@@spid,
@EventTime,
@HostName,
@AppName,
@LoginName,
@ClientHost

END
GO
```

Then just remove it.

Comment: And after that I get this error: cannot login to sql server due logon trigger
I launch mssql in single user mode and drop the trigger.